# How to call AWS API Gateway Endpoint with Cognito Id (+configuration)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I want to call an `AWS API Gateway Endpoint` that is protected with **`AWS_IAM`** using the `generated JavaScript API SDK`.

I have a **`Cognito UserPool` and a `Cognito Identity Pool`**. Both properly synced via `ClientId`.

I use this code to `Sign in` and get the `Cognito Identity`

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // your identity pool id here
});

AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // your identity pool id here
});

var poolData = {
  UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXXXXXXX',
  ClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);


var authenticationData = {
  Username: 'user',
  Password: '12345678',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var userData = {
  Username: 'user',
  Pool: userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
  onSuccess: function (result) {
  console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId,
    Logins: {
      'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_XXXXXX': result.idToken.jwtToken
    }
  });

  AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {
    // now I'm using authenticated credentials
    if(err)
    {
      console.log('error in autheticatig AWS'+err);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log(AWS.config.credentials.identityId);

    }
  });
  },

  onFailure: function (err) {
    alert(err);
  }

});
```

All this succeeds and I have an `authorized Cognito Identity` now.

Now I try to call the `API Gateway Endpoint` to execute the `Lambda Function` it points to.

```
  var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId, //'ACCESS_KEY',
    secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey, //'SECRET_KEY',
    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken, // 'SESSION_TOKEN', //OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token
    region: 'us-east-1' // OPTIONAL: The region where the API is deployed, by default this parameter is set to us-east-1
  });

  var params = {
    // This is where any modeled request parameters should be added.
    // The key is the parameter name, as it is defined in the API in API Gateway.
  };

  var body = {
    // This is where you define the body of the request,
    query: '{person {firstName lastName}}'
  };

  var additionalParams = {
    // If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that must be
    //   sent with the request, add them here.
    headers: {},
    queryParams: {}
  };

  apigClient.graphqlPost(params, body, additionalParams)
    .then(function (result) {
      // Add success callback code here.
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (result) {
    // Add error callback code here.
    console.log(result);
  });
```

But unfortunately this fails. The `OPTIONS` request succeeds with `200` but the `POST` then fails with `403`.

I am pretty sure that there is no `CORS` problem here.

I am pretty sure the problem has to do with `IAM Roles` and `AWS Resource Configurations`.

My question is basically, can you please provide me with all the necessary `AWS Resource Configurations` and `IAM Roles` that are necessary for this to work please?

Resources I have are

- API Gateway - with deployed API Endpoints
- Lambda Function - called by the Endpoint
- Cognito User Pool - with App synced to the Identity Pool
- Cognito Identity Pool - with Authorized and Unauthorized Role mapped to it.
- IAM Roles - for the Lambda Function and the Authorized and Unauthorized Role of the Cognito Identity Pool.

But I don't know how these Resources need to be configured properly to get this to work.

Thank you

Comment: How did you protect the gateway with `AWS_IAM`? I didn't see that as an option under Authorizers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What access permissions does the role of the Cognito Identity have? Make sure it has access to perform `execute-api:Invoke` on your API.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"           
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account>:<rest-api>/*/POST/graphql"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get the exact resource ARN from the method settings page in the web console.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Even after following everything I was getting the same error. And the reason was I missed the "sessionToken" while initialising the apigClient.

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId, //'ACCESS_KEY',
secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey, //'SECRET_KEY',
sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken, // 'SESSION_TOKEN', //OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token
region: 'us-east-1' // OPTIONAL: The region where the API is deployed, by default this parameter is set to us-east-1 });
```

**//OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token**  -- is not really optional

Comment: With Cognito, you are using temporary credentials.  But using Cognito is itself optional, you could just use standard credentials, but it's not recommended.  Anyway, you *could*, so that's why that comment says it's optional.